# WHERE OR AND multiple use MYSQL

Tags: mysql, where-clause

God damn confused at the syntax for my MYSQL query.

Is this correct... Can't find an entry in internet similar to it.

```
$query_game_string = '';

while($game = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_game_list)){
    $query_game_string .= ' OR target = "' . $game['id'] . '" AND ancestors = "0"';   
}

echo '' . $query_game_string . '';  

//prints: OR target = "11" AND ancestors = "0" OR target = "12" AND ancestors = "0" OR target = "27" AND ancestors = "0" OR target = "29" AND ancestors = "0" OR target = "32" AND ancestors = "0"


        $database->connect(); 

            $comments = mysql_query(
                'SELECT * 
                    FROM ' . $database->db_prefix . 'comments 
                        WHERE user_id = "' . $user->user_object["id"] . '"' .
                        $query_game_string . '                                    
                        ORDER BY created DESC'
            , $database->connection_handle);                     

        $database->close();
```

So the actual query would be in total:

```
'SELECT * 
    FROM ' . $database->db_prefix . 'comments 
        WHERE user_id = "' . $user->user_object["id"] . '"' .
        'OR target = "11" AND ancestors = "0" OR target = "12" AND ancestors = "0" OR target = "27" AND ancestors = "0" OR target = "29" AND ancestors = "0" OR target = "32" AND ancestors = "0"' . '                                    
        ORDER BY created DESC'
```

Is the syntax okay?

Comment: Probably you mean to enclose these groups in `()` `OR (target = 11 AND ancestors = 0) OR (target = 12 AND ancestors = 0) ...`\

Comment: But all of that simplifies down (since ancestors = 0) to `(target IN(11,12,27,29,32) AND ancestors = 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know exactly what your are looking for but probably you need parenthesis:

```
OR (target = "11" AND ancestors = "0")
OR (target = "12" AND ancestors = "0")
OR (target = "27" AND ancestors = "0")
OR (target = "29" AND ancestors = "0")
OR (target = "32" AND ancestors = "0")
```

php to achieve that:

```
while($game = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_game_list))
{
    $query_game_string .= ' OR (target = "' . $game['id'] . '" AND ancestors = "0")';   
}
```

a way to simplify the query is using `IN` operand

```
 OR target IN("11","12","27","29","32") AND ancestors = "0"
```

php:

```
$targets = array();
while($game = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_game_list))
{
    $targets[] = '"'.$game['id'].'"';   
}
$query_game_string = ' OR target IN (' . implode(",",$targets) . ') AND ancestors = "0"';
```

Comment: God thankyou. I love the IN way! that's just sexy! Thankyou good sir!